# Disabling vaadin component comunication

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin 7 portlet application. One view contains fields for password change. However, there is architectural policy, that passwords should never be sent to container where my application resides. Password change request should be send to servlet on diferent container.

To fulfill this requirement i need to disable client-server communication of password field, so password value is not send to server at all. After client clicks to change password, custom javascript should be executed which sends ajax request to change password servlet.

I know this solution is dirty, but that is only way to satisfy requirements. Is there a way to accomplish this in vaadin 7? It would be also nice to be able to make simple validations on client - eg password lenght and regex.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had nearly similar requiremet for one of the project -  had to emcrypt fields data before sending it to server. Only way I found is to extend Vaadin TextField widget or PasswordField in your case and implement necessary behaviour at client side by yourself. It will require extending of client and server side as well.

Comment: Thank you. By extending you mean class that extends PasswordField or new Vaadin 7 Extensions? Could you provide some sample code of your implementation please? Thank you.

Comment: I did my implementation for vaadin 6, so I etended VTextField and TextField: `code` public class VEncryptedTextField extends VTextField implements Paintable `code` ,  but for vaadin 7 Extensions should be used